# Open Wifi Settings by "prefs:root=WIFI" failed in iOS 10

Tags: ios, wifi, ios10

I was using prefs:root=WIFI url scheme in my app with prefs entered in info.plist to open directly the iOS settings application in Wi-Fi settings and it was working great on iOS 9 but it does not work anymore on iOS 10.

Does anyone know if this is just a regression in the first developer preview or the way to open Wi-Fi settings has changed in iOS 10 or it is not allowed anymore?

Comment: The `prefs:` URL scheme was never officially supported.

Comment: But our app need to open wifi settings. Do you known any other API works.

Comment: App-Prefs:root=WIFI works for me

Answer (score 24):

Just so it's explicit: Apple does not allow this. It's possible your app will make it through anyway, but this is the same as using any other undocumented API.

[Here is the full list](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899) of supported Apple URL schemes.

[Here's a thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/65007) where Apple confirms that "any Apple URL schemes that are not officially documented should be considered private API."

Comment: This is the most important part, other answers may work and might make it through the review too, but if apple points this out, it's an serious issue thereafter. Better avoid private API's.

Comment: My app also rejected with this API.

Answer (score 13):

SWIFT 3.0:- working in iOS 10

```
@IBAction func openWifiSetting(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let url = URL(string: "App-Prefs:root=WIFI") //for WIFI setting app
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(url!)
}
```

Comment: Whoa! I had given up hope that this was possible post iOS 10.x. Have you found any reason to believe doing this will get an app rejected by the App Store?

Comment: iOS11 is also OK

Comment: This is forbidden by the app store guidelines, I just had an app rejected by the review team for doing this.
"Your app uses the "prefs:root=" non-public URL scheme, which is a private entity. The use of non-public APIs is not permitted on the App Store because it can lead to a poor user experience should these APIs change."

Comment: Mine was rejected too, after a couple of updates. Whoever find this answer helpful - you should realize all the risks. They don't just reject, but also add a note: "Continuing to use or conceal non-public APIs in future submissions of this app may result in the termination of your Apple Developer account"

Answer (score 6):

My app is also using that api. Unfortunately apple disable this on iOS 10. Here's my solution: below iOS 10, it can still open Setting App. on iOS 10, it will go to a subpage(Cellular Data access) of Setting App, you can back to setting page by one click. I decide to keep it. because it's still convenient than user manually open Setting App.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=WIFI"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
} else {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
}
```

Answer (score 6):

try this for objective c in iOS 10

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=WIFI"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]) {
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
} else {
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"App-Prefs:root=WIFI"]];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using "App-Prefs:root" instead of "prefs:root"

Comment: "To resolve this issue, please revise your app to provide the associated functionality using public APIs or remove the functionality using the "prefs:root" or "App-Prefs:root" URL scheme." I got this when my app was rejected.

Comment: Me too ! I got the same rejection ! (for > iOS11 your answer is wrong!)

Answer (score 2):

iOS 10, to open your apps settings:

```
if let settingsURL = URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) {  
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(settingsURL)
          }
```

Comment: this leads to App-Settings but not to general iPhone-Settings.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine on iOS 10,

> Go to Targets --> (Application) --> Info --> URL Types --> +

In the `URL Schemes` write

> prefs

Then Call,

```
- (void)openWifiSettings
{
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=WIFI"]]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=WIFI"]];
    } else {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"App-Prefs:root=WIFI"]];
    }
}
```

Comment: any solution for > iOS 11 ??

Comment: I have the same question.