# How to programmatically open the WIFI settings in Objective-C on iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, wifi, ios10

The following code works fine on iOS 9, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33437815/how-to-programmatically-open-the-wifi-settings-in-objective-c-in-ios9) post. But it doesn't work on iOS 10. How to open WIFI settings programmatically on iOS 10

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=WIFI"]];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works fine on iOS 10,

> Go to Targets --> (Application) --> Info --> URL Types --> +

In the `URL Schemes` write

> prefs

See the image,
[image]

Then add the following code,

```
-(void)openWifiSettings{
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=WIFI"]]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=WIFI"]];
    } else {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"App-Prefs:root=WIFI"]];
    }
}
```

Comment: In iOS 11 `App-Prefs` takes me to the app specific preferences, not the wifi screen.

Comment: same question here: In iOS11 App-Prefs takes me to the app specific preferences, not the wifi screen. how to solve it in iOS11+ ?

Answer (score 12):

The same exact code should work, but for iOS 10 you need to do some additional work by adding "prefs" to the URL Types:

After selecting your target:

- Navigate to "Info" tab.
- After scrolling to bottom, you should see "URL Types" section.
- Add a new one (by clicking on the plus button) and fill the "URL Schemes" with "prefs".

It should be similar to this:

[image]

Now, your code should works fine.

**UPDATE:**

If it -somehow- did *not* work as expected, you might want to follow this [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39782970/5501940).

Hope that helped.

Comment: openUrl is depreciated

Comment: You'll get rejected. They detect use of "prefs" urls now

Answer (score 8):

In iOS 10, a new url is required. Try using this code which tests both urls :

```
NSArray* urlStrings = @[@"prefs:root=WIFI", @"App-Prefs:root=WIFI"];
for(NSString* urlString in urlStrings){
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]){
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatly no official documentation, but some pages already reference a lot of them, for example https://gist.github.com/phynet/471089a51b8f940f0fb4

Comment: Unlike others this one worked for me also for iOS 10

Comment: My app just got rejected for this. Do not use

Answer (score 3):

Try this one :

```
    if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]options:[NSDictionary dictionary] completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
        }];
    }
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4.2, iOS 12**

It's not longer possible to do that kind of deeplinking with the newer version of iOS. My app was recently rejected for using: "*non-public URL scheme*", such as: `prefs:root=`. So I'd say to not waste your time with something that we can't currently do, and simply open the settings.

This is the function that I'm currently using in my app for it:

```
extension UIApplication {

    ...

    @discardableResult
    static func openAppSetting() -> Bool {
        guard
            let settingsURL = URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString),
            UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(settingsURL)
            else {
                return false
        }

        UIApplication.shared.open(settingsURL)
        return true
    }
}
```

Usage: `UIApplication.openAppSetting()`

Comment: so this will simply take to settings page and not exactly on wifi list page, correct ?

Comment: Exactly, we can't open the settings page unfortunately. (or at least, not in a production app at the moment)

Answer (score -1):

For Swift:

```
let url = URL(string: "App-Prefs:root=WIFI")

    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url!){
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url!)

    }
```

Comment: This will get your app rejected

Answer (score -2):

```
 let url=URL(string: "App-Prefs:root=WIFI")
// you can change root as your requirements 
        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url!)
        {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url!, options: [:], completionHandler: {success in

            })

        }
        else{
            UIApplication.shared.open(url!, options: [:], completionHandler: {success in

            })
        }
```