# bluetooth plugin to direct to ios bluetooth settings

Tags: cordova, plugins, ionic-framework, bluetooth

in my app i need to direct to bluetooth settings of the phone.

With android i am using this plugin

cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-bluetooth-serial

which allows me to take the user to the bluetooth settings of the phone. but  I'm unable to find a similar solution for iOS which would take the user to iOS bluetooth settings. As of now I'm using

https://github.com/erikhuisman/cordova-plugin-opensettings.git

for iOS which takes the user to general settings. I would be grateful if someonecould give me some suggestions to solve this sticky problem.

regards
jim

Comment: You dont need a plugin. Do it as shown here for [wifi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40126813/how-to-programmatically-open-the-wifi-settings-in-objective-c-on-ios-10).

Comment: hi i should have mentioned my is in ionic/cordova.do you have a solution for that?

Comment: Ive written bluetooth apps in android and ios, but I have not used a plugin.  I just did the api for use with a serial profile.

Comment: can you please show me an example for how its done as im not able to figure out:(