# How to guide user to Wifi settings in iOS device (iOS 13 swift)

Tags: swift, wifi, settings, ios13, connectivity

For example:

user clicks a button navigate to settings page in the device  connect the wifi required and back to application.

Comment: You write a "how to open settings and change the WiFi" view - opening the WiFi settings directly from within the App is considered a "private API" and will be rejected by Apple

Comment: Hi , Is it possible with

Comment: UIApplication.shared.openURL(NSURL(string:"App-prefs:root=WIFI")! as URL)

Comment: Yes, you "can" do it - but Apple considers it a "private api" and will reject your app if you try submitting it to the App store - [more reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39782510/open-wifi-settings-by-prefsroot-wifi-failed-in-ios-10)

Comment: So apple currently does not allow to open settings directly from the App?

Answer (score 0):

Please try.

```
UIApplication.shared.openURL(NSURL(string:"App-prefs:root=WIFI")! as URL)
```